# Microsoft Graph - Update mailbox settings with SDK

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, outlook, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I'm trying to set automatic replies for Microsoft users using the [example here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-update-mailboxsettings?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp).
The difference from the docs is that I'm trying to do this not for `me`, but for another user using permissions. Getting error: `The OData request is not supported`
The issue is mentioned [here](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/5007) and [here](https://update%20mailbox%20settings%20with%20SDK). But both are closed.
The one solution mentioned is [here](https://gist.github.com/jasonjoh/f4d9ec4c9eae01c23bad12eadf409088) but for this I'm getting the error `Access is denied. Check credentials and try again`.
Does anyone know of a way to set automatic replies / update mailbox settings in microsoft graph using the c# sdk using the `users` option - not `me`?

Comment: Do you get any progress sir?

Comment: @TinyWang adding application permissions helped! but the code in the answer still doesn't work. only the GitHub workaround

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using application api permission is right here and we may also refer to the [workaround](https://gist.github.com/jasonjoh/f4d9ec4c9eae01c23bad12eadf409088) mentioned by OP which worked for him.

===========================================

According to the [api document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-update-mailboxsettings?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#request), it support Application permission,

[image]

So could you pls try this code:

```
using Azure.Identity;
using Microsoft.Graph;

var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
var tenantId = "your_tenant_name.onmicrosoft.com";
var clientId = "azure_ad_app_id";
var clientSecret = "client_secret";
var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
    tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);
var mailboxSettings = new MailboxSettings
{
    AutomaticRepliesSetting = new AutomaticRepliesSetting
    {
        Status = AutomaticRepliesStatus.Scheduled,
        ScheduledStartDateTime = new DateTimeTimeZone
        {
            DateTime = "2022-07-03T18:00:00",
            TimeZone = "UTC"
        },
        ScheduledEndDateTime = new DateTimeTimeZone
        {
            DateTime = "2022-07-07T18:00:00",
            TimeZone = "UTC"
        },
        ExternalReplyMessage = "I'm on vacation.",
        InternalReplyMessage = "I'm on vacation."
    }
};
var user = new User();
user.MailboxSettings = mailboxSettings;
await graphClient.Users["user_id"].Request().UpdateAsync(user);
```

And pls **don't forget to add Application api permission MailboxSettings.ReadWrite** in Azure AD.

[image]

Comment: I tried your code @tinywang but still getting the error `The OData request is not supported` After I added the permissions you mentioned - the [github workaround](https://gist.github.com/jasonjoh/f4d9ec4c9eae01c23bad12eadf409088) now works! But your example still errors even after adding the permissions.

Comment: Thanks for informing me sir, I checked the workaround you shared and it looks like a charm. It seems to send http request manually to call the api. I'll also add it in my post.