# Microsoft Graph - Scheduled AutomaticRepliesSetting Error

Tags: c#, outlook, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I'm trying to schedule automatic replies for Microsoft users using the workaround [here](https://gist.github.com/jasonjoh/f4d9ec4c9eae01c23bad12eadf409088). I asked a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72833321/microsoft-graph-update-mailbox-settings-with-sdk) but that was solved with adding permissions. Now I'm getting the error 'The scheduled duration for sending automatic replies isn't valid'. Setting the status to `AlwaysEnabled` does work. I can't understand what I am doing wrong.

```
private static async Task<GraphServiceClient> SetOOOFinal(string fromEmail, DateTime start, DateTime end, string message)
        {
            string clientId = "myClientId";
            string tenantId = "myTenantId";
            string clientSecret = "myClientSecret";

            IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
                .Create(clientId)
                .WithTenantId(tenantId)
                .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
                .Build();

            ClientCredentialProvider authProvider = new ClientCredentialProvider(confidentialClientApplication);

            GraphServiceClient appOnlyClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);

            var mailboxSettings = new MailboxSettings
            {
                AutomaticRepliesSetting = new AutomaticRepliesSetting
                {
                    Status = AutomaticRepliesStatus.AlwaysEnabled, //working
                    //Status = AutomaticRepliesStatus.Scheduled,   //NOT working. Error: The scheduled duration for sending automatic replies isn't valid
                    //ScheduledEndDateTime = new DateTimeTimeZone
                    //{
                    //    DateTime = "2022-07-08T18:00:00",
                    //    TimeZone = "UTC"
                    //},
                    //ScheduledStartDateTime = new DateTimeTimeZone
                    //{
                    //    DateTime = "2022-07-09T18:00:00",
                    //    TimeZone = "UTC"
                    //},
                    ExternalReplyMessage = message,
                    InternalReplyMessage = message,
                    ExternalAudience = ExternalAudienceScope.All
                }
            };

            try
            {
                // Get the request URL to the user from the SDK and add the /mailboxsettings segment
                var requestUrl = $"{appOnlyClient.Users[fromEmail].Request().RequestUrl}/mailboxsettings";

                // Use the SDK's serializer to generate the JSON payload
                var jsonPayload = appOnlyClient.HttpProvider.Serializer
                    .SerializeAsJsonContent(mailboxSettings);

                // Create a new Http request message with the JSON payload
                var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("PATCH"), requestUrl)
                {
                    Content = jsonPayload
                };

                // Authenticate the message
                await appOnlyClient.AuthenticationProvider.AuthenticateRequestAsync(requestMessage);

                // Send the request
                var response = await appOnlyClient.HttpProvider.SendAsync(requestMessage);

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Updated mailbox settings");
                    // If needed, deserialize the response body
                    var responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    var responseObject = appOnlyClient.HttpProvider.Serializer.DeserializeObject<MailboxSettings>(responseBody);
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new ServiceException(new Error
                    {
                        Code = response.StatusCode.ToString(),
                        Message = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()
                    });
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.Message}");
            }

            return appOnlyClient;
        }
```

Comment: In your code sample it seems you have at least mixed up start and end date. You start date is after the end date. I could understand the api if its thinks thats invalid.

Comment: @Ralf that was the issue. wew! I struggled with this silly mistake. thank you!